# Jquery Table Filter with Tag

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

Need to a jquery for tag from filtered data,
Here is my code for "Filter Data From Table Using Jquery"
JS Fiddle For This is at http://jsfiddle.net/7BUmG/2/

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Type to search">
<table id="table">
   <tr>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>Green</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Grapes</td>
      <td>Green</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>Orange</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
td {padding: 4px; border: 1px #CCC solid; width: 24.5%;}
```

**Jquery Code**

```
var $rows = $('#table tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {
var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

$rows.show().filter(function() {
    var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    return !~text.indexOf(val);
}).hide();
});
```

Now I want to add tag scheme in this search filter,
i.e when user filter data with "Apple" and When click on "Apple", "Apple" should be tagged.